# SUPEE-6788 and disabled extensions

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions, security, supee-6788

I have a couple of extensions which are not compatible with SUPEE-6788. I wish to disable them until the vendors have updated them but the question is would they still be a security risk?

I presume it wouldn't be as the extensions would be disabled but I thought it might be good to get confirmation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you disable them by setting true to false in their app/etc/modules XML files, you're safe.

I reckon doing it by disabling modules output is risky.